# Check if the following position of a pointer is null or end of line C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, null

Well, I have an iterator over a string in C++

```
std::string::iterator itB = itC->begin();
```

And I want to check if **the next position** of the iterator reaches the end of the line. I've tried this:

```
if(*itB ++ != NULL)
```

Also this:

```
itB++ == itC->end()
```

But now I'm really confused and I need some help, since I'm a rookie at pointers in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check it *without* modifying it. Both of your attempts involve modifying `itB`. If you have C++11, that's just [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next):

```
std::next(itB) == itC->end()
```

If you don't, just make another iterator:

```
std::string::iterator next = itB;
++next;
next == itC->end()
```

Although, in this case specifically we know that `std::string::iterator` is a random access iterator, so we can also just do:

```
itB + 1 == itC->end()
```

(The previous two work for any iterator category)

Comment: Plot twist:  itC is an iterator over a list of strings, sorry I didn't put it clear.